# How to change Eclipse's internal browser?

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome, internet-explorer, browser, eclipselink

I am using Eclipse version 4.8.0 (Photon).
I have one website I want to open inside this eclipse internal browser. When I use Eclipse's internal browser to open one website , that website is opening but few functionalities are not working.

On further investigation , I found out that -

1. Website is using ES6 syntax so its not working on Internet Explorer.
2. Eclipse is using Internet Explorer as its internal browser

I tried following things , but could not make it work

1. Change Eclipse browser setting  at **Preferances -> Web Browser -> Select Chrome** (Image 1 and 2).
2. Add below property in eclipse.ini file  `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=webkit`
   After adding this property , I am getting error while opening browser (Image 3)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Eclipse Photon (4.8) is more than 4 years and 17 releases behind. Your problem is caused by using that old version instead of the current.

Comment: @howlger  Is there any setting to make eclipse use  installed chrome/mozilla/edge as internal browser ?

Comment: No, since as far as I know, chrome/mozilla/edge do not provide an API to be used in another application. In the past, XULRUnner could be used to embed Firefox (to deliver it as part of the application). Unfortunately, XULRUnner has been abandoned by Mozilla. If latest IE is not enough, you might consider embed Chromium either from [Equo](https://equo.dev/chromium) ([GitHub](https://github.com/equodev/chromium)) or [Yatta Solutions](https://github.com/YattaSolutions/org.eclipse.swt.browser.electron). See also this talk: https://youtu.be/_87vJwChNKE